# How can I detect if caps lock is toggled in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build a better username/password field for my workplace and would like to be able to complain when they have their caps lock on.

Is this possible?  And if so I'd like to have it detected before the client types their first letter.

Is there a non-platform specific way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this, from java.awt.Toolkit, returns a boolean:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't work on all platforms. For instance, it throws a UnsupportedException under OpenJDK-6 in Linux. :(

Comment: as others have pointed out, this throws an error on Linux.  Interestingly, there must be an internal way to do it in Linux, as Gnome displays the message "You have the caps lock key on." when it is on and the screen is locked.  Perhaps OS has APIs but java has not implemented them?  using jdk 1.6 and fedora 14

Answer (score 1):

here is some info on the class
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState(int)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nick's answer, to react to this condition before the user presses a key, you can listen to the focus event of your text entry component and test the caps-lock as the component receives focus.