# Method to check whether caps-lock is on or not in java

Tags: java, swing, methods, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect if caps lock is toggled in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88434/how-can-i-detect-if-caps-lock-is-toggled-in-swing)

How to detect ( method to know ) whether the capslock is on or not in java application because I wants to see to user when user enter password in my application.

Comment: +1 for interesting question, even though it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  boolean state= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                        .getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean capsIsOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                  getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);`

Related: [How can I get the Caps Lock state, and set it to on, if it isn't already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435221/how-can-i-get-the-caps-lock-state-and-set-it-to-on-if-it-isnt-already)

Use Google before asking, please ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isCapsLock = 
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```