# How do I check if the caps lock key is pressed?

Tags: java, capslock

Alright, before this gets flagged as a possible duplicate, I've already tried the following code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)
```

And it is always returning false for me [see below]. Could someone confirm if this is supposed to be working, and I'm misusing it, or if it's known to be broken? If it is in fact broken, does anyone have a better method to use?

**EDIT:**

Alright, just found out something more. It appears to just return what it was at the begining of my programs launch. If I start the program with it on, it says its on, and vice versa. Here's my code:

```
while (true) {
    boolean isOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(
        KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
    System.out.println("Caps lock is now: " + (isOn ? "ON" : "off"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

And that's just always printing out whatever it started as

(ex. if I start with caps lock on, even if I toggle it off right after, it prints:

> Caps lock is now: ON
>
> Caps lock is now: ON
>
> Caps lock is now: ON
>
> Caps lock is now: ON

etc., if I start with it off, it will print off no matter what)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88434/how-can-i-detect-if-caps-lock-is-toggled-in-swing

Comment: What does or doesn't work will depend on your environment.  What is it?  A GUI environment is entirely different from the command line environment.

Comment: @assylias, yes, already saw that, its just not working for me.

Comment: @Hot Licks Not sure what you mean by that, but see my edit

Comment: Can you try this peace of code please : [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160315/how-to-check-for-key-being-held-down-on-startup-in-java

Comment: related? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414164

Comment: -1 for not specifying environment.

Comment: @HotLicks Umm. -1 for you being dumb? I said not sure what you mean by that, meaning please explain further. You don't downvote people because they ask you what you meant by something.

Comment: @Abdousoft That will work fine, the issue is that later on in my code if I call it again, it still returns the value when the program was started, even if the caps lock state has changed.

Comment: Are you running under a GUI environment?  If so, which one?  Or are you just running the program from the command line (what OS?) or from an IDE (which one?)?

Comment: @HotLicks I was running from Eclipse, on Windows, but I didn't want the OS to affect it (meaning if you had a solution for windows, i wanted it to work on any OS tho)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poking around, I think `getLockingKeyState()` might be broken.

You could try [KeyboardUtils](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/KeyboardUtils.html), but it looks like that means you have to carry JNA overhead.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using some JNI, and add global key listeners; since I can get the caps lock state when started, and detect when its changed (when the button is pressed), I should be able to just keep track of it in a boolean and toggle when needed

Comment: @Dave could you give an example of KeyboardUtils usage?

Comment: @AlexejMagura: sorry, no. It's something I know of, but have never used.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was always broken or at least since Java 1.3 (see [Bug 4414164](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414164)).

Not sure for other platforms, but for **Windows** I can say this: State change of Caps Lock can be detected, but only if your awt client has the focus. However, there is this workaround which works for me:

```
boolean isCapsLockOn() {
    java.awt.Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);  
}
```

Contraint: Your awt app must have the focus before calling `isCapsLockOn`.

Note: Your robot might press any other key which is not harmful to your app. Might depend on your use case.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void checkOnOff() {
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                if (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
                    jLabel4.setForeground(Color.red);
                    jLabel4.setText("CAPSLOCK is ON");
                } else {
                    jLabel4.setText(null);
                }
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }                    
            }
        }
    };th.start();
}
```

Comment: you can replace jLabel4.setText(YOURTEXT) with system.out.println()

Comment: Please explain your solution as well, don't write just the code.