# Detect CapsLock in Java

Tags: java, windows, capslock

I want to determine the current state of CapsLock using Java. I have tried the following so far.

1. `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)` always returns true
2. I cannot use key listeners as they will inform about CapsLock key being pressed or released but what I want is to detect whether CapsLock is on/off.

Is there any other possible way to check the state of CapsLock key in Java?

Comment: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); works for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the Caps Lock state, and set it to on, if it isn't already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435221/how-can-i-get-the-caps-lock-state-and-set-it-to-on-if-it-isnt-already)

Comment: try KeyboardUtils from checking link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020835/how-do-i-check-if-the-caps-lock-key-is-pressed

Answer (score -1):

`getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)`

Read more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState%28int%29