# How is the Java Toolkit.getLockingState(int) implemented?

Tags: java, toolkit

From [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/Toolkit.java?av=f) I found this:

```
public boolean getLockingKeyState(int keyCode)
        throws UnsupportedOperationException
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless();

        if (! (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK ||
               keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_KANA_LOCK)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid key for Toolkit.getLockingKeyState");
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Toolkit.getLockingKeyState");
    }
```

It just looks as though it throws exceptions.

Is this because it's for openJDK, and therefore unsupported for linux? I thought Java was meant to run on all platforms?

How is it implemented in the Oracle version?

I want to know, as it relates to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/88434/1075247)

Comment: This is a platform specific implementation, and if you search the bug database, you'll see a number of complaints about it that are still open.  Example: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4834514 It also doesn't seem to be too high on their priority list either.